# how to store models in folders

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 separate portals and don't want to mix all the models in one folder. I tried separating the models into 3 separate folders but it wouldn't work codeigniter kept saying that the models weren't found. I even tried

```
$this->load->model('folder_path/my_model');
```

as of now i am doing this for example (admin, members, and public)

```
admin_my_model
members_my_model
public_my_model
```

Would there be another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter does support one subfolder under `models` so:

```
$this->load->model('admin/my_model');
```

should work (where `admin`is a subfolder of CI's `models`directory). Be sure to only include the relative path from your models folder (so not the full path all the way up from your CI install).

See also: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading

Answer (score 0):

create `modules`  folder under application folder. 
then under modules create `members`  folder for member module. in members folder it will contain 3 folders

```
1) controllers (will contain member.php controller)

2) models  (will contain members_model.php model)

3) views  (will contain members_view.php view)
```

then load your model like this

```
$this->load->model('members/members_model');
```